# Как исправить ошибку Segmentation fault?

Tags: c

Поиск количества инверсий с помощью сортировки слиянием.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int merge(int* a, int l, int mid, int r) {
    int inv = 0;
    int buf[4096];
    int i = l;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (i <= mid && j <= r) {
        if (a[i] < a[j]) {
            buf[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else {
            buf[k++] = a[j++];
            inv += mid - i + 1;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
        buf[k++] = a[i++];
    while (j <= r)
        buf[k++] = a[j++];
    for (int i = 0; i <= (r); i++)
        a[i] = buf[i];
    return inv;
}

int merge_sort(int* a, int l, int r) {
    int inv = 0;
    if (l == r)
        return inv;
    int mid = (r ) / 2;

    inv += merge_sort(a, l, mid);
    inv += merge_sort(a, mid + 1, r);
    inv += merge(a, l, mid, r);

    return inv;
}

int main()
{
    int a[4096];
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    int inv = merge_sort(a, 0, n - 1);

    printf("%d", inv);
}
```

Comment: inv += merge_sort(a, l, mid); -

Comment: `int mid = (r ) / 2;` => `int mid = (l+r ) / 2;`

Comment: В `merge` индексация массива `a` начинается с `l`. А результат записываете с индекса `0` в массив `a` из буфера `buf`. Внимательно пишите и добавляйте комментарии к коду, чтобы не запутаться.

Comment: Научиться линковать либасан